# Naming Columns in R

Tags: r, csv

I was hoping someone could help me fix this coding:

```
read.csv(file="file:///C:/Users/Erin/Downloads/clausen.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
read.csv(file="file:///C:/Users/Erin/Downloads/Mather.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
c(rep(1,8),rep(2,17),rep(3,12),rep(4,18),rep(5,26),rep(6,31))
c(rep(1,8),rep(2,17),rep(2,12),rep(2,18),rep(3,26),rep(3,31))
cbind(c(rep(1,8),rep(2,17),rep(3,12),rep(4,18),rep(5,26),rep(6,31)),c(rep(1,8),rep(2,17),rep(2,12),rep(2,18),rep(3,26),rep(3,31)))
cbind(Mather,c(rep(1,8),rep(2,17),rep(3,12),rep(4,18),rep(5,26),rep(6,31)),c(rep(1,8),rep(2,17),rep(2,12),rep(2,18),rep(3,26),rep(3,31)))
```

I need to name the columns Ecotype (the first line of data) and Subspecies (the second line).

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do, please provide a valid code snippet and what the expected output should look like. This being said, for some matrix or data.frame `df` with k columns you would set the column names by `colnames(df) <- name_vec`  where `name_vec` is a vector of characters of length k.

Comment: what are the read.csv() for, here?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to store your data after reading in from read.csv then you change the column names like this.

```
df <- read.csv(file="file:///C:/Users/Erin/Downloads/clausen.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",") 
colnames(df) <- c("Ecotype","Subspecies")
```